# Object of type Response is not JSON serializable in rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to call one method response into another method in Django rest framework.

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def GetCurrentRunningActivityForAudit(request, UserID):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        
   
        print("current running activity--userid--", UserID)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
       
        data = []
        for row in result_set:
            TaskId=row[0]           
            TaskName = row[1]
            Source = row[2]
            SID = row[3]
            type = row[4]
           
            data.append({
                    "TaskId": TaskId, "TaskName":TaskName,"Source":Source,
                    "SID":SID, "type":type, "IsActive":GetCurrentSubTaskSTatus(TaskId)})
        

            return Response(data[0])   
        return Response(data)
```

I'm passing this method response to the above method response i.e.,. GetCurrentRunningActivityForAudit but it's show as Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

```
def GetCurrentSubTaskSTatus(taskid):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCurrentTaskStatus] @taskid=%s',(taskid,))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result_set:
        IsActive =row[0]
    return Response({"IsActive":IsActive})
```

Comment: Why does `GetCurrentSubTaskSTatus` return a `Response` and not just a dict, it's not a view and its return value is being used as part of another dict?

Comment: GetCurrentSubTaskStatus  return the response from the Stored Procedure, This response should be used to the GetCurrentRunningActivityForAudit response

Comment: `Response` objects are HTTP responses that should be returned from API views, it's not meant for returning from functions that just return some result. Remove it from the `GetCurrentSubTaskSTatus` function and just return a dict

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you are passing a dictionary having Response as value at key IsActive to Response class.

Remember `Response clas` does not return a JSON but returns a complete Response object and it expects a dictionary as an input so that is why you get are getting an error.

```
An object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

If you want to solve this issue you can do it by removing Removing Response from this line

```
 return Response({"IsActive":IsActive})
```

you need to write it as simple

```
 return {"IsActive":IsActive}
```

And the views Response will take care of the nested dictionary so you do not have to worry about it.

Corrections is here

```
def GetCurrentSubTaskSTatus(taskid):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCurrentTaskStatus] @taskid=%s',(taskid,))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result_set:
        IsActive =row[0]
    return {"IsActive":IsActive}
```